# Matlab 2015a object handle

Tags: matlab

### Update:

I'm afraid I've mislead you a bit.
When trying to assign, say, an axes to a figure, everything works fine. The problem is with a class I'm trying to create.

### Code:

```
classdef figContainer

properties
    parent;
    hTabPanel;
end

methods
    function obj = figContainer(varargin);
        if nargin == 0
            obj.parent = gcf;
        else
            obj.parent = varargin(1);
        end
        hTabPanel = uipanel(...
                'parent'    ,   obj.parent , ...
                'units'     ,   'normalized' , ...
                'position'  ,   [0 , 0.95 , 1 , 0.05]);   
    end

end
```

Now I can't seem to pass the handle right:

[image]

Comment: hFig is the handle already! Just use it...

Comment: to get the numeric handle like you are used to, use `hf=double(hFig)` ... but that said the handle you got was a perfectly valid handle to manipulate your figure anyway.

Comment: This [article](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html) talks about that.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature ! Matlab now uses objects for all graphical handles. You can still access the properties with `get` and `set`, so what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` must be changed to `{}`:

```
classdef figContainer
...
    else
        obj.parent = varargin{1};
    end
...
```